# How to pass a bind variable to a view for a for loop

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I have to deploy my sql script and for that I have defined variable in one file and the create script in another file.

File 1:

```
Define_Variable.sql
```

DEFINE hr_SCHEMA = hr;
File 2:

```
Createfile.sql


declare
lctr varchar2(200);

BEGIN

  for rec in (select view_name,count(1) as cnts from all_views where owner='&hr_SCHEMA .' AND VIEW_NAME IN('employee_user_v','employee_id_v') group by view_name)

LOOP
    if (rec.cnts = 1) THEN
        lctr:='DROP VIEW :owner.' || rec.view_name ;
        execute immediate lctr  using '&hr_SCHEMA.';
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DROPPED VIEW OF..'|| rec.view_name);
    else
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('no view found in the system');
    end if; 

END LOOP;
END ;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you executing this? Anonymous PLSQL does not share variables across blocks. There is no "global" variable and therefore no way to pass & access it. Your choices are:
In SQLPLUS you can define a variable and use that, or create a PLSQL package with the variable thus making it global. Or, use the database and store the value in a (temporary) table and select it for use in the second script. 
Also, never us an anonymous block on its own. [Always use a package](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:7452431376537) (and your param passing problem is solved as well).

Comment: The variable has been passed from a define variable .sql file, all table scripts has been placed in create_table.sql and all views in create_view.sql file. I have created a master.sql file , upon calling, will call define_Variable.sql first and the table scripts next and so on.